# why does my code assign boolean to instance self in python

Tags: python, dynamic, pyqt

I'm using a dynamic function as `getattr()`
But I don't why my code assign boolean value to self instance and its return follows: *AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'key'*

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui()

    key = 0
    btns = ["Next", "Back"]

    def ui(self):
        for a in range(0, 2):
            btn = QPushButton(self.btns[a], self)
            btn.move(20, 20 * a + 10)
            btn.clicked.connect(getattr(MyApp, self.btns[a]))

#//////////////////////////////// it's only UI //////////////////////////////////

        self.setWindowTitle('Question')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)

        self.label1 = QLabel('0', self)
        self.label1.move(20, 60)

        self.show()

#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    def Next(self):
        if self.key < 5:
            self.key += 1
        self.label1.setText(self.key)

    def Back(self):
        if 1 <= self.key:
            self.key -= 1
        self.label1.setText(self.key)

#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\project\pyeditor\QnA.py", line 31, in Next
> if self.key < 5:
> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'key'

I use a fairly large number of buttons, but I have only taken two buttons as an example to make it easier for you to understand the question. It is generated as a repetitive statement. I also know that if I write button functions one by one, I don't have to worry about the data type of instance values. But then the purpose of factoring is overshadowed. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `btn.clicked.connect(getattr(MyApp, self.btns[a]))` is the issue.
Here you are connecting to the functions `MyApp.Next` and `MyApp.Back` instead of the function `self.Next` and `self.Back`. The difference is that the class `MyApp` does not know `self` since only an instance of `MyApp` can access it.

**How to fix**

Replace `btn.clicked.connect(getattr(MyApp, self.btns[a]))`

with `btn.clicked.connect(getattr(self, self.btns[a]))`.

**Edit**

You also have a small error with setText where you need to convert self.key to a string.